# Spring Hibernate Not Mapping Entity to Existing Table in PostGres

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi I have an issue with hibernate where it does not map an entity Called "summoners" to an existing table in Postgre called "summoners"

[image]

> Postgre version: 9.2
>
> Sts version: 4.4.2.RELEASE

summoners.java

```
package hello;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "summoners")
public class summoners {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SummonerName")
    private String SummonerName;
    @Column(name = "SummonerEncryptedID")
    private String SummonerEncryptedID;
}
```

SummonerRepository.java

```
package hello;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface SummonerRepository extends CrudRepository<summoners, Integer> {

}
```

GreetingController.java

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    @Autowired 
    private SummonerRepository summonerRepository;


    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/summoners")
    public Iterable<summoners> summoners() {
        return summonerRepository.findAll();
    }


}
```

**FIXED**

The issue was that postgre 9.2.0 has trouble with columns that start with an uppercase character ...

Answer (score 0):

Nice to hear its fixed.

Apart from that, I could see

```
public interface SummonerRepository extends CrudRepository<summoners, Integer>
```

shall be

```
public interface SummonerRepository extends CrudRepository<summoners, String>
```